# http server that counts requests

Tags: python, http

I am learning to use python to run an HTTP server and wanted to make a server that would count every time I refresh. I tried this:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

count = 0

class HelloWorldRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        count = count + 1
        self.wfile.write(str.encode(count))

httpd = HTTPServer(("localhost",8000),HelloWorldRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

but I get an error that count doesn't have a value.
help appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign to a global variable without using the `global` keyword:

```py
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

count = 0

class HelloWorldRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        global count  # now you can modify/use it
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        count = count + 1
        self.wfile.write(str.encode(count))

httpd = HTTPServer(("localhost",8000),HelloWorldRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```